# Variadic parameters and defaulted parameters

Tags: swift

I have this function:

```
func sum(#startingValue:Int, additionalValue:Int = 77, values:Int...) -> Int {
    var total:Int = startingValue + additionalValue
    for v in values {
        total += v
    }

    return total
}
```

Is there any way I can call it without specifying value for additionalValue argument?

What I want is something like this:

```
sum(startingValue:10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: I think no because: "A function type can have a variadic parameter as the last parameter in its parameter type.", The Swift Programming Language -> Language Reference -> Types -> Function Type.

Comment: Sorry but no, all parameters are required in Swift and they have to be ordered in the same way as declared as well

Comment: Check my edit and see if it will work for you.

Comment: What is that "#" doing inside the function argument? I am seeing this for the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this may seem like a weird work around, it does work, you can use method overloading:

```
// Calling this will result in using the default value
func sum(#startingValue:Int, values:Int...) -> Int {
    return sum(startingValue: startingValue, values);
}

// Calling this will use whatever value you specified
func sum(#startingValue:Int, #additionalValue:Int, values:Int...) -> Int {
    return sum(startingValue: startingValue, additionalValue: additionalValue, values);
}

// The real function where you can set your default value
func sum(#startingValue:Int, additionalValue:Int = 77, values:Int[]) -> Int {
    var total:Int = startingValue + additionalValue
    for v in values {
        total += v
    }

    return total
}

// You can then call it either of these two ways:
// This way uses will use the value 77 for additional value
sum(startingValue:10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) // = 115

// This way sets additionalValue to the value of 1
sum(startingValue:10, additionalValue: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) // = 38
```

To be honest, I am not entirely sure why your first solution did not work automatically, in the docs I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_204):

> If your function has one or more parameters with a default value, and
>   also has a variadic parameter, place the variadic parameter after all
>   the defaulted parameters at the very end of the list.

But was unable to make it work, maybe a bug? I would guess it is supposed to work the same way I showed you. If you specify `additionalValue` it will use it, otherwise it will use the default. So maybe it will work automatically in the near future (making this solution irrelevant)?

#### Original Answer

The solution below works if you solely want to cease using the word `additionalValue` while calling the function but it still assigns `additionalValue` an argument (not what the OP was looking for).

Put an underscore in front of `additionalValue`:

```
func sum(#startingValue:Int, _ additionalValue:Int = 77, values:Int...) -> Int {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can call it how you want without warnings:

```
sum(startingValue:10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

In this case `additionalValue` automatically equals the second parameter, so it would be equal to `1`

Comment: This allows him to use that syntax, but is logistically different. In the function if he uses `values` directly he will be missing the first number that he expects to be there, since it was passed to `_additionalValue`

Comment: @JackWu, oh... I misunderstood the original question then. I thought by "without specifying value", he meant that he did not want to explicitly state the word `additionalValue`.

Comment: @Firo Interesting, I guess he is ambiguous here...it might be the case that your understanding is correct :p, I understood it as he wanted to not pass that parameter, since they are named.

Comment: @JackWu, given that he is setting a default value, you are probably correct... Let me think about this.

Comment: @JackWu, you are right. I don't want to specify any value for `additionalValue` arg. It should use it's default value 77.

Comment: @Cezar, see my edit, if you will. As you see, I just misunderstood the original question.

Comment: I see, looks great now :).

Comment: Great edit! Interesting use of overloading, I would be slightly worried about using this in practice but it does work

Comment: @JackWu, Thanks! Yeah, I would probably not use this either and instead just call the main one, but as you said, it does work. It was fun to figure out too.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2 (and 1.2) you can, as long as you use an argument label for “values”:

```
func sum(startingValue startingValue:Int, additionalValue:Int = 77, values:Int...) -> Int {
    var total:Int = startingValue + additionalValue
    for v in values {
        total += v
    }

    return total
}

sum(startingValue:10, values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
sum(startingValue:10, values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, additionalValue: 177)
sum(startingValue:10, additionalValue: 277, values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: For (slightly) more, see http://blog.nottoobadsoftware.com/swift/mixing-default-values-and-variadic-parameters/